# TAP Windows Adapter V9

Tags: network-adapter

I just reinstalled Windows 11 and now my TAP Windows Adapter V9 shows unplugged.  Everything that I have tried has failed to solve the problem.  I have a VPN that uses it.  My Proton VPN connects to all servers but none of my browsers connect to websites with the VPN on. Connects with VPN off.

What can I do to get the adapter to connect?

I ran the following CMD's
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset

turned on ProtonVPN and I was able to connect to one site. I tried other sites and none would connect. I went back to the site that connected before and it would not connect.

I repeated the procedure above and received the same result. One site connected only one time.

Comment: You did reinstall the Proton VPN client already, right?

Comment: Yes I have reinstalled it many times.  I am assuming that it is this adapter that prevents me from connecting to websites when the VPN is on.

Comment: It is a good idea to add any info we ask for to the question itself to make the question better. We only know what you tell us about your problem, so the better your description is, the more likely you are to get a good answer.

Comment: Hints: (1) Answering your own question – [right thing](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer). (2) Deleting the answer and posting it in the question body – wrong thing. (3) Putting "solved" in the title – [wrong thing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/355310). (4) Accepting a good answer to indicate the problem is solved – [right thing](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: I rolled back your question and made your answer ready for you to undelete it and accept it. Note maybe you have to wait several hours before you are allowed to accept your own answer, this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of the question.

The problem with internet connectivity was being caused by a conflict between ProtonVPN and Adguard Premium.  The "DNS Protection" switch in Adguard settings was preventing anything from connecting to the internet with the VPN connected.  I disabled the switch in Adguard settings and the problem was solved.